# why i am having an error like Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails?

Tags: php, mysql, syntax

I am having an error like this and idk why what is wrong with it.

**Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`studentsinformation`.`honor`, CONSTRAINT `honor_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ExamineeID`) REFERENCES `personal` (`ExamineeID`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php:74 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php(74): mysqli_stmt->execute() #1 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Practice\dummy.php on line 74**

These are my codes:

```
else{


        $sql = "SELECT FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, LastSchoolAttended From personal Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ? Limit 1";
        $sqlhonor = "SELECT Honor1, Honor2, Honor3, Honor4 From honor Where Honor1 = ? And Honor2 = ? And Honor3 = ? And Honor4 = ? Limit 0";
        $sqlparent = "SELECT Father, EducationalFather, Mother, EducationalMother, Guardian, Occupation From parent Where Father = ? And EducationalFather = ? And Mother = ? And EducationalMother = ? AND Guardian = ? AND Occupation = ? Limit 0";

    if ($stmt = $conn->prepare($sql)); {

        $INSERTpersonal = "INSERT INTO personal (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, HomeAddress, ContactNumber, LastSchoolAttended, Strand, SchoolAddress, Adviser) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";

        $stmt -> bind_param("ssss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmt -> execute();
        $stmt -> bind_result($FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
        $stmt -> store_result();
        $rnum = $stmt -> num_rows;

        if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmt->close();
            $stmt = $conn -> prepare($INSERTpersonal);
            $stmt -> bind_param("sssisissss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Age,$HomeAddress,$ContactNumber,$LastSchoolAttended,$Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser);
            $stmt -> execute(); 
        }
    }
     if ($stmthonor = $conn->prepare($sqlhonor)) {
                $INSERThonor = "INSERT INTO honor (Honor1,Honor2,Honor3,Honor4) values (?,?,?,?)";
                $stmthonor -> bind_param("ssss", $Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
                $stmthonor -> execute();
                $stmthonor -> bind_result($Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
                $stmthonor -> store_result();
                $rnum = $stmthonor -> num_rows;

            if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmthonor->close();
            $stmthonor = $conn -> prepare($INSERThonor);
            $stmthonor -> bind_param ("ssss", $Honor1, $Honor2, $Honor3, $Honor4);  
            $stmthonor -> execute();    
        }
    }

        if ($stmtparent = $conn -> prepare ($sqlparent)) {
            $INSERTparent = "INSERT INTO parent (Father, EducationalFather,Mother,EducationalMother,Guardian,Occupation) values (?,?,?,?,?,?)";
            $stmtparent -> bind_param("ssssss", $Father,$EducationalFather,$Mother,$EducationalMother, $Guardian, $Occupation);
            $stmtparent -> execute();
            $stmtparent -> bind_result($Father,$EducationalFather,$Mother,$EducationalMother,$Guardian ,$Occupation );
            $stmtparent -> store_result();
            $rnum = $stmtparent -> num_rows;

            if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
            $stmtparent->close();
            $stmtparent = $conn -> prepare($INSERTparent);  
            $stmtparent -> bind_param ("ssssss", $Father, $EducationalFather, $Mother, $EducationalMother, $Guardian, $Occupation); 
            $stmtparent -> execute();
        }
    }
```

}

All I want is that, for example, if I am filling the needed information, I want them to be distributed to their own tables, but still have the connection to each other (which is why I assigned the FK), but in my situation, they aren’t distributing at all, and only the personal table was filled, while the others, it is blank and showing errors like that.

Fiddle of my Database that I wanted it to be:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pYIY2.png)

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210312/discussion-on-question-by-kansai-why-i-am-having-an-error-like-uncaught-mysqli-s).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A very basic exapmle for solving the problem.

**NOTE** provided code can only be used as an exaple and maybe will help you solve your problem. I put as much comments there as I could.

The code posted below first basically makes sure that a record with the given params exists in `personal` table. These params include ExamineeID.

Next it tries to select data from `honor` table using ExamineeID firstly making sure it the previous queries for getting ExamineeID completed successfully.

If a record with this ExamineeID already exsist in `honor` then nothing happens, if such record does not exist, then it will be inserted there

The code is working on database structure you provided in [This fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pA6tnGP9eRonr7K2LqCtR6/3)

```
<?php
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT); // Turn on mysqli exeptions. Much better than errors.
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'user', 'pass', 'db'); //Initialize Db connection

// Generic values for testing
$FirstName = "test";
$MiddleName = "test";
$LastName = "test";
$Age = 1000;
$HomeAddress = "test";
$ContactNumber = 1000;
$LastSchoolAttended = "test";
$Strand = "test";
$SchoolAddress = "test";
$Adviser = "test";
$Honor1 = "test";
$Honor2 = "test";
$Honor3 = "test";
$Honor4 = "test";
$Father = "test";
$EducationalFather = "test";
$Mother = "test";
$EducationalMother = "test";
$Guardian = "test";
$Occupation = "test";
$ExamineeID;

/**
*
* Pay great attention. You have to actually select ExamineeID from table personal, so you need to add it as a selected param.
* Also we limit our result to a single row, ideally this whould not be done with LIMIT 1,
* but in reality we don't have any other way of making sure only one record is selected, using provided.info.
* As I understand it an ExamineeID which solves the selection problem can actually be unknown on the time of selection
*
*/
$sql = "SELECT ExamineeID, FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, LastSchoolAttended From personal Where FirstName = ? And MiddleName = ? And LastName = ? And LastSchoolAttended = ? LIMIT 1";

/**
*
* Pay even greater attention. Honor1, Honor2, Honor3,Honor4 are being selected and should non be in that where clause.
* Determining correct values that should be selected is based on ExamineeID, which should be somehow provided.
* but in reality we don't have any other way of making sure only one record is selected, using provided.info.
* As I understand it an ExamineeID which solves the selection problem can actually be unknown on the time of selection
*
*/
$sqlhonor = "SELECT Honor1, Honor2, Honor3, Honor4 From honor Where ExamineeID = ?";

/**
*
* This statements doesn't relate to problem in any way. Any queries will be omitted as they just bring confusion
*
*/
$sqlparent = "SELECT Father, EducationalFather, Mother, EducationalMother, Guardian, Occupation From parent Where Father = ? And EducationalFather = ? And Mother = ? And EducationalMother = ? AND Guardian = ? AND Occupation = ?";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql); // You don't need this if. If this fails then you will get exeption.

$stmt->bind_param("ssss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($ExamineeID,$FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
$stmt->store_result(); // As I understand it store_result() doesn't actually fill values specified in bind_result().
$stmt->fetch(); // fetch on the other hand fills  bind_result variables.
$stmt->close();

if (!isset($ExamineeID)) {  // We don't check the number of rows, we check if and ExamineeID was actually found in previous query
  $INSERTpersonal = "INSERT INTO personal (FirstName, MiddleName, LastName, Age, HomeAddress, ContactNumber, LastSchoolAttended, Strand, SchoolAddress, Adviser) values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)";
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($INSERTpersonal);
  $stmt->bind_param("sssisissss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$Age,$HomeAddress,$ContactNumber,$LastSchoolAttended,$Strand, $SchoolAddress,$Adviser);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();

  // After we add a value to personal table we have to re-select all values.
  $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bind_param("ssss", $FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->bind_result($ExamineeID,$FirstName,$MiddleName,$LastName,$LastSchoolAttended);
  $stmt->store_result();
  $stmt->fetch();
  $stmt->close();
}

//Here 
if (isset($ExamineeID)) { // We only need to check that we actually found a $ExamineeID earlier.
  $stmthonor = $conn->prepare($sqlhonor);
  $stmthonor->bind_param("s",$ExamineeID); // We need to bind only a single value as I pointed out earlier.
  $stmthonor->execute();
  $stmthonor->bind_result($Honor1,$Honor2,$Honor3,$Honor4);
  $stmthonor->store_result();
  $stmthonor->fetch(); // Again fetch is needed to actually fill Honor vars

  $rnum = $stmthonor->num_rows;
  $stmthonor->close();
  // If no entries that have ExamineeID we found earlier exist in Database.
  if ($rnum == 0 ) {  
    $INSERThonor = "INSERT INTO honor (Honor1,Honor2,Honor3,Honor4,ExamineeID) values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"; // We need to insert 5 values!!

    $stmthonor = $conn->prepare($INSERThonor);
    // We actually insert a record with provided ExamineeID, because earlier there was no such record.
    $stmthonor->bind_param ("ssssi", $Honor1, $Honor2, $Honor3, $Honor4, $ExamineeID); 
    $stmthonor->execute();   
    $stmthonor->close();    
  }
}
```

Comment: To close the question you can accept the answer). Note: It was just an example, but it is adaptable. I am glad it helped you somehow

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to this. I can now move to my next task. This helped me a lot! Thank you again sir!!